# How could I perform a JOIN over 5 tables and get the data I need?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB with 5 tables representing surveys and their questions, users' responses and a mailing list to keep info about email that I've sent.

I generate guids for users to make it impossible to pass other user's survey (there's no authentication in my app) and store those guids both in mailing list table and response table.

Here is the DB schema:

[image: DB]

When frontend requests survey by guid so that user could answer it, I put a simple SELECT query:

```
SELECT 
   se.survey_id, se.id, se.`type`, se.title
FROM 
  survey_element AS se 
    JOIN mailing_list AS ml  
      ON se.survey_id = ml.survey_id
WHERE ml.guid = '7658bc0f768bd5e0'
ORDER BY se.`order`
```

this gets me

```
survey_id  id  type           title
1          1   head_question  How do you feel?
1          5   idea           Do you have any ideas?
```

(also see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rktX4mjfxKLwGA1izbQFoV/2)

Everyting works fine, but now I want to select answers to the questions if there were any. So, same guid, same questions (survey elements), and I want to get the output for the user that answered '1' to the first question, and didn't answer the second quesion:

```
survey_id  id  type           title                     answer
1          1   head_question  How do you feel?          1
1          5   idea           Do you have any ideas?    (NULL)
```

I've tried different ways, but I get either multiple question with the same title (since multiple users answered it) or the same answer for the question user haven't really answered.

Like that (gives multiple entries, see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2yQJ1q7jDzQMNWGBxNB6br/3):

```
SELECT 
  se.survey_id, se.id , se.`type`, se.title, re.answer
FROM 
  survey_element AS se 
    JOIN mailing_list AS ml 
      ON se.survey_id=ml.survey_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN response_element AS re
      ON re.survey_element_id = se.id
WHERE ml.guid = '7658bc0f768bd5e0'
ORDER BY se.`order`
```

All the data is there, but I just can't select it the right way :-\

Any ideas on how to do that?

DB server is MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are possibly missing a `JOIN` between `response` and `response_element`?  It doesn't show in your data model, but I assume it would work the same as `survey_element` to `survey` does?  If it does work this way then this query appears to work:

```
SELECT 
    se.survey_id, 
    se.id, 
    se.`type`, 
    se.title, 
    re.answer
FROM 
    survey_element AS se 
    INNER JOIN mailing_list AS ml ON se.survey_id = ml.survey_id
    INNER JOIN response r ON r.guid = ml.guid
    LEFT JOIN response_element AS re ON re.survey_element_id = se.id 
        AND re.response_id = r.id
WHERE 
    ml.guid = '7658bc0f768bd5e0'
ORDER BY 
    se.`order`
```

This gives you a list of questions and responses for Joe, where there is a NULL because he didn't answer the second question.

```
survey_id   id    type            title                    answer
1           1     head_question   How do you feel?         1  
1           5     idea            Do you have any ideas?   null
```

Actually, re-reading your question I can see that `response_id` in `response_element` has a `(FK)` postfix, which makes me even more sure that this is just an omission from your schema/ data model?

Comment: The only thouble here... what if user haven't submitted any response, and still needs his questions to ask?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2yQJ1q7jDzQMNWGBxNB6br/6 - here is an example with Jill. She has no response, and she's getting no survey. So secont `INNER JOIN` should be replaced with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as far as I can see.

Comment: Agreed, if you want to include people who haven't answered any questions then use a LEFT JOIN to response instead.